# Streaming camera feed from mjpeg-streamer with Flask (Python)

Tags: python, html, flask, mjpeg

I'm trying to stream a webcam feed from  mjpeg-streamer through flask in a simple web app. My flask code has a simple piece of html, which otherwise works, which I insert the following line into:

```
<img src=”/?action=stream”/>
```

But the picture doesn't load. I've tried varying this with things like making the source have localhost:8080 (mjpeg-streamers port), and I've had no luck. I've seen that for images, they should be in your static folder, but that doesn't quite seem to apply here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in web browsers. I assume you're running your flask application on port 5000, and your mjpeg-streamer is running on port 8080. This fails because you're trying to import a resource from another port.

If you setup apache or similar to front your application, you can proxy the mjpeg-streamer so that everything is served from the same port, and the browser will pickup the stream correctly.